# Integral of $e^{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I find the integral of $e^{x^3}$.

I have to do find the following integral and when I try to do integration by parts, I cannot find the integral of $e^{x^3}$.

$$\int x^2 e^{x^3} \;\mathrm{d}x$$

I tried to get the integral of $e^{x^3}$ on my calculator but it does not give a solution and on Wolfram Alpha it gives me some really complicated answer that involves the gamma function.

Comment: Take $u = x^3$ ...

Comment: Yeah, this is a substitution problem of the type "one part of this function looks like the derivative of another part".

Comment: The title of your question and the integral you wrote down are *obviously* different...

Comment: @symplectomorphic, I need the integral of e^x^3 to get the other one

Comment: @Quantitative: no you don't.........

Comment: @symplectomorphic, so how?

Comment: @Quantitative: are you not reading the other comments? This is a simple $u$-substitution problem. You're wrong to want to apply integration by parts.

Comment: Remember that $\int p(x)q(x)dx\ne(\int p(x)dx)(\int q(x)dx)$. So trying to integrate based on factors isn't a good idea.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp\big(-\sqrt[\large^n]x\big)~dx ~=~ n!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $t=x^3$. Then $dt=3x^2dx$ and $x^2dx=\frac{dt}{3}$ You have
$\int \frac{1}{3}\int e^t dt=\frac{1}{3}e^t+C=\frac{1}{3}e^{x^3}+C$

Answer (score 3):

Only a quick calculation, but I get:

$$\int_0^ x e^{x^3} dt=e^{x^3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(3^n)x^{3n+1}} {\prod_{k=0}^n (3k+1)}$$

Maybe it works.
e.g. how to calculate

$$ \prod_{k=0}^3 (3k+1) = 1*4*7*10$$.

I apologize if the answer is not correct. I have not verify.

Comment: ... This answers the question he asks, but not he one he is trying to solve

Comment: Nevertheless, it is deserving of an upvote for those that come here looking to solve the harder problem

Comment: @  frogeyedpeas.  thanks that was unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find the primitive of solely $e^{x^3}$, simply because it doesn't have any. You can calculate it in terms of other integrals, but if you want to calculate $\int x^3e^{x^3} dx$, then I agree with kmitov.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question, but it was not pointed out that you can solve $$\int x^2e^{x^3}dx$$ just by noticing that $$\frac{d}{dx}e^{x^3}\;=\; 3x^2e^{x^3}\,.$$ Therefore, $$\int x^2e^{x^3}dx\;=\;\frac 13e^{x^3}+C\,.$$